# Group by and do aggregate function like sum and count on a list of values

Tags: python, pandas

Group by shows, Count the corresponding VideoID, Sum the views and Sum the revenue. How can I achieve this?

My table looks like

```
    show.    views.  revenue  VideoID
    batman.   100.     10.    v1
    batman.   200.     20.    v2
    joker.    100.     10.    v3
    joker.    300.     15.    v4
    superman. 500.     30.    v5
```

My expected output is

```
Show          total_views    total_revenue.    video_count
batman.           300.            30.           2
joker             400.            25            2
superman          500             30            1
```

How can I achieve this?

This is what I tried so far but getting wrong output

```
def grouping_series(df_series):
    t = defaultdict(list)
    gp = df_series.groupby('show')
    for i, k in gp:
        t['total_views'].append(k['views'].sum())
        t['total_revenue'].append(k['revenue'].sum())
        t['video_count'].append(k['VideoID'].count())
    return pd.DataFrame(t)

df = grouping_series(df_series)
```

Comment: Show what you tried so far so we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually do agg

```
s=df.groupby('show').agg(total_views=('views', 'sum'), 
                         total_revenue=('revenue', 'sum'),
                         video_count=('VideoID', 'nunique')).reset_index()
        show  total_views  total_revenue  video_count
0    batman.        300.0           30.0            2
1     joker.        400.0           25.0            2
2  superman.        500.0           30.0            1
```

Comment: Is there a way to get distinct count? just in case if same VideoID is present for same series twice, it must calculate only once

Answer (score 2):

This is my suggestion:

```
iimport pandas as pd

frame = {
    "show": ["batman", "batman", "joker", "joker", "superman"],
    "views": [100, 200, 100, 300, 500],
    "revenue": [10, 20, 10, 15, 30],
    "VideoID": ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(frame)

aggretations = {"views": "sum", "revenue": "sum", "VideoID": "nunique"}

df.groupby(["show"]).agg(aggretations)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get distinct count? just in case if same VideoID is present for same series twice, it must calculate only once. say batman has video Id V1 and V1. the video count should be 1 and not 2